# Парсинг строки в виде неориентированного множества

Tags: c++, строки, парсер

Необходимо разбить строку(std::string) на элементы множества. Как пример, для множества  **{a, b, c}** разложением на элементы будет **a, b, c.** А для множества **{{a}, {b}, {c}}** - **{a}, {b}, {c}**. Кроме того, **{{a, b, c}, d}** в результате разбиения даст **{a, b, c}, d.**
Идей, как написать для этого регулярное выражение у меня нет.

Comment: А надо обязательно через регулярные выражения?...

Comment: @Harry, нет, не обязательно. Я пытался сделать что-то через find и substr, но использовал как разделитель ", ", поэтому, элементы которые идут как дискретные, у меня соответственно разбивались.

Comment: Понимаете, в том виде, как вы поставили задание :) — достаточно просто убрать внешние скобки, и вы получаете нужную вам строку...

Comment: @Harry, да, действительно. Я не добавил пробелы куда следовало.

Comment: А вот теперь вообще ничего не понял. Какие пробелы?

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в итоге? Строку? `std::set<std::string>`?

Comment: Рекурсивные подмножества должны оставаться нетронутыми? А вообще — это очень простой КА, например. Кстати, что такое "неориентированное множество"? Неориентированный граф — понятно, но множество?

Comment: Дело в том, что элементом множества может быть другое множество. Поскольку я не совсем правильно поставил пробелы, и, видимо, не совсем корректно сформулировал вопрос. Например множество {{a, b, c, d}, {1, 3}, a}. Его элементами являются {a, b, c, d}(первый элемент) {1, 3} (второй элемент) a(третий элемент). Эти элементы мне и нужно получить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Строку. Задание заключается в том, что нужно написать функционал неориентированного множества. Это я сделал. Одним из пунктов является сформировать такое множество из строки. Это я не сделал.

Comment: @Harry, неориентированное множество - множество элементов, в котором порядок следования элементов роли не играет. Как пример между множествами {1, 2} и множествами {2, 1} можно поставить знак равно. А вот между множествами {{2}, 1} и {2, 1} нельзя.

Comment: Если строку, то просто уберите первую и последнюю скобку? Но похоже вам нужно получить не строку, а ваш собственный класс множества, который вы почему-то нам не показываете.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это вам ничего не даст. Я могу добавлять элементы в свое множество с помощью строки. Убирая первую и последнюю скобку в множестве {{1, 2, 3}, 4} и потом разделяя строку с помощью ", " я получу не два элемента, как мне нужно, а 4. А мне необходимо именно {1, 2, 3} и 4 как две отдельные строки, чтобы я мог добавить их в множество.

Comment: Не очень понятно, в чем сложность. Игнорируйте все запятые между скобками. Для этого сделайте счетчик, который увеличивайте на 1 для `{`, и уменьшайте на 1 для `}`.

Comment: Так может, вы говорите об упорядоченном и неупорядоченном множестве?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот, нечто на [коленке бегом набросанное](https://ideone.com/xtX9Oy). Нужную обработку пробелов и защиту от дурака (от `{a{b}}}{` :)) напишите сами, а равно и переделку для своего контейнера...

```
string getElement(const char* &c)
{
    string t;
    while(*c &&(*c == ' ' || *c == ',' || *c == '}')) ++c;
    if (*c == 0) return "";
    if (*c == '{')
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        do {
            t += *c;
            if (*c == '{') cnt++;
            if (*c == '}') cnt--;
            c++;
        } while(cnt);
    }
    else
    {
        while(*c != ',' && *c != '}' )
        {
            if (*c != ' ') t += *c;
            c++;
        }
    }
    return t;
}

vector<string> parse(const string& s)
{
    vector<string> v;
    const char * c = s.data();
    for(;*c && *c != '{'; ++c);
    if (*c++ == 0) return v;
    string t;

    while((t = getElement(c)).size())
        v.push_back(t);
    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(auto s: parse("{ a, b, c }"      )) cout << "[" << s << "]"; cout << endl;
    for(auto s: parse("{ {a}, {b}, {c} }")) cout << "[" << s << "]"; cout << endl;
    for(auto s: parse("{ {a, b} , c }"   )) cout << "[" << s << "]"; cout << endl;
    for(auto s: parse("{ {a, {b}} , c }" )) cout << "[" << s << "]"; cout << endl;
}
```